Does the offline language translation in nodejs possible
Pleaese tell me is it possible, else tell me why
I have downloaded the translation model from hugging face site, and then try to use the nodejs library '@xenova/transformers' which is not able to load the models to test as my model extension is like this model.gguf. But it can load with the model.onnx extension.

Please edit the question to explain what you mean by "not able to load the models". Any relevant error output is best pasted into the question and delimited by triple-back-ticks.

It's easy.
Like this:
import { pipeline, env } from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@xenova/transformers@2.14.0";

const model = await pipeline('translation', 'Xenova/opus-mt-ru-en')
/////wait until the model downloads in full

let transText = await model('пусть всегда будет солнце')

